# why is my plsql function returning an empty string?

Tags: plsql, sqlplus, stored-functions

so here is the conceptual model[image: conceptual model]

There are some sample records inserted into those tables. I need to display the name of the driver, followed by the number of trip legs of the longest trip, which also means if a trip has the most trip legs, it is the longest trip in this context, the trip legs here means the parts of a trip. So this is my function to return a string that contain the driver and the longest trip's trip leg number.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LONGTRIP(DLNUM driver.L#%type) 

RETURN VARCHAR2 IS



mostrip NUMBER;

driveName VARCHAR(100);

FinalANS VARCHAR(100);



BEGIN

SELECT *

INTO mostrip

FROM (SELECT COUNT(leg#) 

     FROM TRIP

      INNER JOIN TRIPLEG USING(T#)

      WHERE L# = DLNUM

      GROUP by T#

      ORDER by COUNT(leg#) desc) T

WHERE ROWNUM = 1 ;



select name into driveName

FROM TRKEMPLOYEE,DRIVER

WHERE TRKEMPLOYEE.E# =DRIVER.E#

AND DRIVER.L# = DLNUM;





FinalANS := driveName  || ' '|| nvl(mostrip, 0); 



RETURN FinalANS;



END LONGTRIP;

/

show error;



SELECT LONGTRIP(L#) FROM DRIVER;
```

So after execute the select query "SELECT LONGTRIP(L#) FROM DRIVER;" the output below shows an empty string between Adam and Frederic, but this is not possible because my string is suppose to return a name followed by a 0 for that row even though this driver hasnt made any trips.

```
   LONGTRIP(L#)
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    John Smith 5
    John Doe 5
    Adam Taylor 8

    Frederic Jones 5
    Adam Fox 4
    John Lucas 5

    7 rows selected.
```

Comment: Did you resolve the issue yourselves? If your comments are relavant to question, please update it to the question.

Comment: Check your data. Maybe you have empty driver.